# Split array into two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
var point = 'c';
```

How can I split the "arr" into two arrays based on the "point" variable, like:

```
['a', 'b']
```

and

```
['d', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: well I did with two iterations and a few temporary variables, but I was hoping there's a faster way and with less code...

Comment: Will the arrays always be composed of single character strings?

Comment: I suggest you write a function that splits an array based on the "point" variable.

Comment: Your question is underspecified: For instance, is the array guarenteed to be in sorted order? Or are we just looking for the first instance of the split point value and splitting on that?

Comment: I'd recommend using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) followed by [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: @bernie The code is there, and the question is clear. OP just doesn't know what methods can be used to do what they need

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
var arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
arr = arr2.splice(0, arr2.indexOf('c'));
```

To remove 'c' from arr2:

```
arr2.splice(0,1);
```

arr contains the first two elements and arr2 contains the last three.

This makes some assumptions (like arr2 will always contain the 'point' at first assignment), so add some correctness checking for border cases as necessary.

Comment: Actually that should be `arr2.indexOf('c') + 1`.

Comment: Fixed...for this specific case, at least.

Comment: How could you do this same thing in ruby?

Answer (score 41):

Use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

var indexToSplit = arr.indexOf('c');
var first = arr.slice(0, indexToSplit);
var second = arr.slice(indexToSplit + 1);

console.log({first, second});
```

Comment: the `end` index is exclusive (contrary to `start` which is inclusive), so it should be `second = arr.slice(indexToSplit);` (no need to add 1)

Comment: @TomaszGawel I'm not sure what you mean, this gets the output the OP asked for, that is, they don't want the matching item in either array.

Answer (score 33):

Sharing this convenience function that I ended up making after visiting this page.

```
function chunkArray(arr,n){
     var chunkLength = Math.max(arr.length/n ,1);
     var chunks = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         if(chunkLength*(i+1)<=arr.length)chunks.push(arr.slice(chunkLength*i, chunkLength*(i+1)));
     }
     return chunks; 
 }
```

Sample usage:

```
chunkArray([1,2,3,4,5,6],2);
//returns [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

chunkArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],2);
//returns [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]

chunkArray([1,2,3,4,5,6],3);
//returns [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

chunkArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],3);
//returns [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

chunkArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],42);//over chunk
//returns [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]]
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks.

Comment: `var` is not the way to go in JavaScript, modern JS code should use `let` and you can use transpilers for older browser support. Also there's no spacing with that  `if` at all.

Answer (score 12):

Try this one:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
var point = 'c';

var idx = arr.indexOf(point);

arr.slice(0, idx) // ["a", "b"]
arr.slice(idx + 1) // ["d", "e", "f"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
var point = 'c';
Array.prototype.exists = function(search){
    for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == search) return i;
    }
    return false;
} 

if(i=arr.exists(point))
{
    var neewArr=arr.splice(i);
    neewArr.shift(0);

    console.log(arr); // output: ["a", "b"]
    console.log(neewArr); // output: ["d", "e", "f"] 
}​
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UA2ch/1/).

Comment: Your `exists` function already exists, it's called `indexOf`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
var point = 'c';
var i = arr.indexOf(point);
var firstHalf, secondHalf, end, start;

if (i>0) {
  firstHalf = arr.slice(0, i);
  secondHalf = arr.slice(i + 1, arr.length);    
}
```

//this should get you started. Can you think of what edge cases you should test for to fix?
//what happens when point is at the start or the end of the array?

Answer (score 1):

When splitting the array you are going to want to create two new arrays that will include what you are splitting, for example arr1 and arr2. To populate this arrays you are going to want to do something like this:

```
var arr1, arr2; // new arrays
int position = 0; // start position of second array
   for(int i = 0; i <= arr.length(); i++){
       if(arr[i] = point){ //when it finds the variable it stops adding to first array
           //starts adding to second array
            for(int j = i+1; j <= arr.length; j++){
               arr2[position] = arr[j];
               position++; //because we want to add from beginning of array i used this variable
            }
       break;
       }
      // add to first array
       else{
           arr1[i] = arr[i];
       }
}
```

There are different ways to do this! good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yet another suggestion:

```
var segments = arr.join( '' ).split( point ).map(function( part ) {
    return part.split( '' );
});
```

now `segments` contains an array of arrays:

```
[["a", "b"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
```

and can get accessed like

```
segments[ 0 ]; // ["a", "b"]
segments[ 1 ]; // ["d", "e", "f"]
```

Comment: This will fail if the array contains something like 'abc'

Comment: @JuanMendes: not really. Why do you think that?

Comment: @JuanMendes: oh.. you mean with a modified array structure. Yes, I'm assuming here that the original array has this exact structure.

Comment: My comment is very clear, this will not work `if the array contains 'abc'` I didn't downvote, it's probably the person that upvoted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to split into equal half; why no simple while loop ?

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
var c=[];
while(arr.length > c.length){
 c.push(arr.splice(arr.length-1)[0]);
}
```

Kaboom :).

Answer (score 0):

#### Separate two arrays with given array elements as string array and number array;

```
let arr = [21,'hh',33,'kk',55,66,8898,'rtrt'];


arrStrNum = (arr) => {
    let str = [],num = [];

    for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(typeof arr[i] == "string"){
            str.push(arr[i]);
        }else if(typeof arr[i] == "number"){
            num.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return [str, num]
    }

let ans = arrStrNum(arr);
let str = ans[0];
let num = ans[1];
console.log(str);
console.log(num);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add a little textual explanation: Why and how does it work and why does it differ from the other answers given.