# JavaScript split and merge arrays by conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array like [a, b, c, d] and I want to split it into 2 arrays like [a, b] and [c, d] and then merge it to have final result like [[a, b],[c, d]]. Is it possible to do without for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933662/split-array-into-two-arrays)

Comment: Why you want to do without loop ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Comment: I guess it's not really possible without loops unless you statically assign indexes to access each. Just use loop for it.

Comment: You gave an example, but do you need code for a more general case? If yes, how would you exactly specify that general case? Alternatively, share the code with the loop(s) and then we will try to rewrite it without loops.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `slice` and `push` method like this

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let index = 2;
let result = [];
result.push(arr.slice(0, index));
result.push(arr.slice(index))
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Everything is fine, but found another way how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

yes without loop you can do this But you should know at what index you have to split the array.

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];  
var indexToSplit = arr.indexOf('c');
var first = arr.slice(0, indexToSplit);
var second = arr.slice(indexToSplit + 1);
var final = [first, second]
    console.log(final);
```

Comment: Please also specify the second step: merging the two pieces together, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [0, 1, 9, 10, 8];
    let arr2 = arr.slice(1,3);
    let resultArr = [];

    if(arr2[1] > 1){
    resultArr.push(99); 
    }
else{
    resultArr.push(100); 

}
    console.log(resultArr)
```

Comment: splice arr array and get new array arr2 and based on condition we push element on result array

Answer (score 0):

You might like something like this:

```
a = 8;
b = { some: 'say'};
c = 'life';
d = true;

let o = {
    'a': [a, b, c, d],
    'a1': [],
    'a2': []
}
nSwitchBefore = 2;

o.a.forEach(function(item, i) {
   i < nSwitchBefore ? this.a1.push(item) : this.a2.push(item) ;
}.bind(o));

console.log(o);
```

Within the function block there is room for extra handling your array items. Like filtering or special treatment of certain types, using all conditions you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for this issue, without writing loops
Lodash Chunk does this logic

```
_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
// => [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

https://lodash.com/docs/