# I need to split an array into N number of arrays based on searching for an element from another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, typescript, angular7

I need to split an array into N number of arrays based on searching for an element from another array.

consider this scenerio

```
var test = ["1","2","3","env","6","7","8","uat","2344","wersdf","sdfs"];
var test2=["env","uat"];
```

now I want a map like

```
{
env:["6","7","8"],
uat:["2344","wersdf","sdfs"]
}
```

Note that the array items in test2 and test1 is dynamic.But two test2 values will not be coming one after another in the test array, there will be some items between it.

Comment: OK. Did you try anything?

Comment: If values from test2 will be repeated and the result is an object some keys will be overwritten.

Comment: @Utkanos  I tried with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933662/split-array-into-two-arrays , but how to do for N number of times I am not sure.

Comment: @KalimahApps  Yes you are right I have added that condition it should not be repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do with `Array#Reduce`

1. First iterate the `test2` array and match the index of `test`
2. Then use the forloop with starting value `ind+1` .it will target the next argument of delimiter
3. After pass the value to array using `acc[b].push()`
4. Then detect next delimiter  using `test2.indexOf(test[i]) == -1`  on else condition.That time you need to break the statement.Then again start the second argument of `test2`

```js
function maper(test, test2) {
  return test2.reduce((acc, b) => {
    let ind = test.indexOf(b); //detect starting index of delimiter
    if (ind > -1) {
      acc[b] = acc[b] || []; 
      for (var i = ind+1; i < test.length; i++) {
        if (test2.indexOf(test[i]) == -1) { //detet next delimiter reach
          acc[b].push(test[i])
        }else{
         break;
        }
      }
    }
    return acc
  }, {})
  
}

var test = ["1", "2", "3", "env", "6", "7", "8", "uat", "2344", "wersdf", "sdfs"];
var test2 = ["env", "uat"];

console.log(maper(test, test2))
```

Comment: Hi how to replace the occurance of a string in an array of string with a different array.  ex  var test1=["1","2"]   I have to replace "1" with var test2=["4","5"]    that is final should be test1=["4","5","2"]   test1 the values of test2 can be repeated. Please help.

Comment: @JananiHariharan You Comment question different from your original question. please post comment as new question . Share link i will post answer on that  or else update the original question with above comment question . Because it more helpful for future visitor  easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

```js
var test = ["1","2","3","env","6","7","8","uat","2344","wersdf","sdfs"];
var test2=["env","uat"];
 
var indexArray = [];

test2.map(key=>{
var index = test.indexOf(key);
  indexArray.push(index);
})
 
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i<indexArray.length; i++){

  var part = test.slice(indexArray[i]+1, indexArray[i+1]);
   obj = {...obj,[test2[i]]: [ ...part]};
}
console.log("obj = ", obj);
```